# SPServices - GetItemList

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spservices

I am using following list and following jQuery Script to get the list items - but it doesn't work - Does anybody have an idea whats going wrong ?

The alerts are working fine, so the jQuery & SPServices Library are loading:
(I am using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise)

[![SP Liste][1]][1]

[image: SP Code]

Not working means that the list is not showing/loading. So to get the list I created a new site and add the *.html (with the code above) into the content part (see picture below)

[image: SP_Content]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Only thing I see is a space in the CAMLViewFields, which could be an issue

Comment: Can you describe what "not working" means? Are there errors in your F12 console?

Comment: Invest time in learning [F12 Developer Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589512(v=vs.85).aspx) it is going to save you heaps of time. As you are on 2013 you might also be better of with [CSR : Client Side Rendering](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)

Comment: Try inserting an alert inside for.each function() to check if its returning any value or not.

Comment: Console Error is: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd.

Comment: Updated my post above regarding what I mean with "not working"...thanks for your help...

Comment: Are alert("jquery") and alert current site working?

Comment: Yes these are working fine

Comment: Is the list on the same site as your page w/ content editor web part?

Comment: Have you checked if the list name is correct?

Comment: The content web part has following url: /Pages/test.aspx

The list has following url: /Lists/liste/AllItems.aspx

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions btw?

Comment: Try removing the CAMLViewFields line and let us know what happens

Comment: permission should be ok (logged in as admin). have removed the CAML Field - still no list items on the site...

Comment: when i include an alert before the  'var liHtml'...then the alert is not working...

Comment: find the solution. according to Niranjans post i added 'webURL' option to my script and now its working fine...thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
       GetEvents();
});


function GetEvents() {
    $().SPServices({
        debug: true,
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        webURL: '/',
        listName: "ListName",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function () {

          /* Your code here  */

            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: THX for your input - with the code line 'webURL' my script is working..

Comment: Would you mark it as an answer then please.